# Why did Lanterns feel fear in front of Parallax?

Tags: dc, green-lantern, green-lantern-2011

In the movie *Green Lantern*, We saw that Kilowog was able to create a gravitational force equivalent to that of our Sun (He showed it to Hal Jordan). If creating Solar gravitational force was very-very difficult, Kilowog wouldn't have used it to train and encourage a newbie. So, I can assume that the best Lanterns like Sinestro etc. were able to create Solar gravitational force.

In the end of *Green Lantern* movie, we did see that Parallax was trapped by the gravitational pull of our Sun. So, *logically* stopping Parallax was very easy for the team of best Lanterns because they should be able to create dozens of sources of 'solar gravitational force'.

But, the problem: At that time, they didn't know that a solar gravitational pull was more powerful than Parallax. So, they tried a trial & error method against Parallax. They failed however. But, instead of re-attacking with more willpower, why did they feel fear? Isn't it like you are afraid of a coming Tiger after hitting it with a stone when you have gun?

Is this ignored for the sake of plot? Or, am I missing something?

Comment: 1. It was Kilowog that created a 'simulation' of a gravitation pull of an average sun, not Sinestro. 2. Your logic is faulty in assuming that being able to create such a pull is what can stop Parallax. 3. GL Hal Jordan didn't plan on using Earth's sun to stop Parallax, he creatively used his surrounding ultimately-- so it shouldn't be assumed that any GL would know how to stop Parallax off the top of their head. 4. Full potential? The GL rings work off willpower, which is different from GL to GL. --- I'm having a hard time understanding this question.

Comment: A success chance of a thousand percent? That does not make any sense.

Comment: @sunpech 1. It was Sinestro. 2. Any explanation? 3. The point is that upon using full potential, Parallax would be defeated. 4. They were best Lanterns, so I can assume that they had great willpower. Tell me where you need more clarification.

Comment: @Junuxx Just a style saying chance was very-very high. Don't expect exact calculation. :)

Comment: @SachinShekhar This [picture](http://imgur.com/ksGYW) from the movie, shows [Kilowog](http://greenlantern.wikia.com/wiki/Kilowog) training Hal with a 'simulated' sun, not [Sinestro](http://greenlantern.wikia.com/wiki/Sinestro). It wasn't the gravitational pull that stopped Parallax, it was that along with the sun. *This question as is, isn't very well researched and the assumptions not well founded.*  I don't see why you think full potential means they could vanquish Parallax.

Comment: @sunpech Oh, I see. Edited the question. My faint memory has just recalled that Kilowog engaged Hal both before and after Sinestro. :)

Comment: @sunpech `Bigger you are, Faster you'll burn` - This was Kilowog's words which came across Hal's mind. But, I am not talking about burning. I am saying only about gravitational force of Sun which was able to stop Parallax. Equivalent gravitational force or even more powerful ones could be created by Lanterns. But, they created a simple weak trap. They failed... no problem. The natural thing: They should try again. But, NO.. they became feared (without even trying more upto highest potential possible).

Comment: I have re-phrased the question to make it constructive...

Comment: Regarding this question being re-opened...I don't see how your edits changed the question enough to make it constructive. It still is making the assertion that, "They could have beaten him all along, so why were they afraid at any point?".

Comment: @NominSim Instead of re-attacking with more willpower, why did they feel fear?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a plot hole. They were using Solar gravitational attack on a newbie for training, but didn't try more powerful attack on a enemy which was threat to their existence. It doesn't matter what the object was, their first trap, which was created by willpower of many Lanterns, should have worked.

I think, filmmakers screwed up after displaying that Solar gravitational force was more powerful than Parallax. Up until that scene, everything was fine. One could assume that their first attack was more powerful than a gravitational pull of a neutron star, but it didn't work because Parallax was even more powerful.